# How to preact signal to build a drop-down list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact-signal

This is my first to use preact/signals.
I am not sure if is it a good practice for using preact/signals.

Would you tell me how can I use the signals for building the drop-down box?

Here is my code:

```
import './App.css';
import Select from 'react-select/async';
import { signal } from "@preact/signals-react";
import {useEffect} from "react";
import fetchAPI from "./utility/fetchAPI.js";

let technicianObjList=signal(null);  
export default function App() {  
  const toSelectOption = ({ id, name, jobtitle }) => ({ label: name + ' ' + ((jobtitle) ? jobtitle : ''), value:{id:id,jobtitle :jobtitle ,name:name}});
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    let getData=async()=>{
      let searchResult = await fetchAPI(...........);
      technicianObjList.value=searchResult.map(toSelectOption);
    }
    getData();
  },[]); 
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <Select
          isClearable
          options={technicianObjList.value}/>
          {(technicianObjList==null)?technicianObjList.value.length:""}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I got the following error message:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__H')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__H')
    at d (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9410:13)
    at p (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9458:11)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/main.4d729e3bd3aede4ff93c.hot-update.js:49:59)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23738:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:27024:17)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28320:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:13330:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:13374:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:13431:35)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33305:11)
```

The `fetcAPI` function is working properly, and the variable `searchResult` contains all the data to build the drop-down box. Unfortunately, the result is the drop-down box contains no options.

How can I populate the API data to the select box?

Comment: Move signal(null) outside of the component and call getData inside useEffect with empty dependency list. You can't assign values directly to ```technicianObjList```, update its property ```value```, ```technicianObjList.value = searchResult.map(toSelectOption);```

Comment: I update the code accordingly, however, it does not work.

Comment: If using a signal in your component, you should be using the useSignal hook. See the [Signal docs](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/signals/#local-state-with-signals)

Comment: I got error message:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__H')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__H')
    at d (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:8946:13)
    at F (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9018:11)
    at useSignal (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2776:63)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49572:85)

Comment: That error typically means you have multiple active copies of Preact in your app which is an issue as it (along with most other UI frameworks) need to be loaded as singletons. Without a full reproduction of your app though, it'd be hard to offer any suggested solutions as it's very tooling-dependent.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using Preact, or React? I can't tell if your import from `react` is using an alias (and therefore `preact/compat`) or if you're using the wrong signals package (`@preact/signals-react` should be used for React apps)

Comment: @TheKNVB I think you misunderstood -- are you using Preact, or React? `@preact/signals` is meant for use in Preact, `@preact/signals-react` is meant for use in React. You cannot use `@preact/signals-react` with Preact (including `preact/compat`), that will not work. You need to clarify what you're actually using.

Comment: I am using React.

Comment: In that case, remove your import from `preact/compat`, use `@preact/signals-react`

Comment: Unfortunately, the error message is gone, but the drop-down box is still empty.

Comment: I follow `rschristian` instruction to modify the code, and the error message is gone, but the drop-down box is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your last comment:

> I follow rschristian instruction to modify the code, and the error message is gone, **but the drop-down box is still empty**.

Probably, React isn't listening for updates of your signals' values yet. As is stated in a relatively hidden part of the docs, you either need to [add some Babel plugin](https://github.com/preactjs/signals/blob/main/packages/react/README.md#babel-transform) to make React listen for updates of signals' values or, alternatively, you can [use the `useSignals()` hook](https://github.com/preactjs/signals/blob/main/packages/react/README.md#usesignals-hook) inside those components that you want to react to signal-value-updates.